# Configuration gets reset, and cannot find BIOS in ePSXe

Tags: pc, emulation, epsxe

I downloaded the PlayStation emulator, ePSXe and it worked fine last night. When I attempted to start a game today, it says it is not configured despite the fact the nothing was changed.

When I attempt to reconfigure it using the wizard, it states that it cannot find the BIOS in the ePSXe folder even though it is still there and worked previously. I also noticed (in the video section of the config menu) that the plugin was no longer selected, so I would not be surprised if this was also not being detected anymore. Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Have you tried re-selecting the video plugin?

Comment: Yep nothing is coming up in the drop down.

Comment: Where did you install the program? In `Program Files`? It sounds to me like a permissions problem since the config files are likely to be written to the installation folder. Try running as an administrator. And a general pointer, never install games in program files directory, that is protected. Install them elsewhere.

Comment: No I installed in in a new folder I made in the same area as video, document, music, etc folders are.

Comment: @A.C.M. - That may also be a protected folder. I have ePSXe installed to `C:\Core\ePSXe` and put games in a sub directory under that (`C:\Core\ePSXe\Games`)

Comment: I'll try moving everything to that location and let you know how it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the info about where you installed the ePSXe folder (as you describe it, your Personal User folder with your Documents, Music folders etc) this is most likely a permissions issue.

**Try moving the ePSXe directory to another directory.**

For example, I have ePSXe installed to `C:\Core\ePSXe` and put games in a sub directory under that (`C:\Core\ePSXe\Games`)

So long as you don't put it in any Windows directories, such as `Program Files`, `Users`, your personal `Home` folder or `Windows` it should be fine.

Comment: A better place would be the homefolder under C:\Users\YourName. Folders made on C:\ might have the ownerflag, but still, it is better to stick to conventions and the home directory is the correct place for anything you create yourself.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness - Based on the OP's comments, He did try the Home folder. As a programmer, I can tell you only bad things will come from following Windows conventions :P. I'm half joking, but there are a few instances like the OP's where things will simply not work properly, based on special permissions assigned to Windows folders. At work, I put all my dev stuff under `C:\Development`, my network sharing folder as `C:\Share`, and my (non-dev) Programs folder as `C:\Core` At home I have a second harddrive, so I replace `C:` with `D:` for all of the above